# Fill a series based on two other series without a for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I have two series: s1 and s2, filled with hourly data over one year. I want to create another series, s3 so that:

- if, for a specific hour, s1> 0 and s1 > s2, s3 = s1
- if s1 > 0 and s1 <= s2, s3 = s2
- if s1 < 0, s3 = 0

So I could do something like

```
for i in range(1,len(s1)):
    if (s1.iat[i] > 0 and s1.iat[i]>s2.iat[i]):
        s3.iat[i] = s1.iat[i]
    elif (s1.iat[i] > 0 and s1.iat[i]>s2.iat[i]):
        s3.iat[i] = s2.iat[i]
    else:
        s3.iat[i] = 0
```

But I'm sure there's a more elegant, and hopefully faster, way to do this. I've tried numerous implementations with boolean indexing and numpy.where, but I don't know how to tell Python to do "a[b>c]=b". It doesn't seem to like comparing different arrays on row-basis.

Answer (score 2):

```
map(lambda a: 0 if a[0]<0 else a[0] if a[0]>a[1] else a[1],  zip(s1,s2))
```

And here's some working..

```
>>> s1=[-1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
>>> s2=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> map(lambda a: 0 if a[0]<0 else a[0] if a[0]>a[1] else a[1], zip(s1,s2))
[0, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

This might help explaining..

```
>>> zip(s1,s2)
[(-1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)]
```

If you take the above and apply it to your code... am not sure if I would be right to do it at my end, as I do not know what `iat` is.

if the arrays are really large I would replace `zip` with `itertools.izip` as that would return an iterator.

Comment: Note that some of the answers given do a 3 iterations one for each condition. I wouldn't do that if my array is as big one year hourly!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like (assuming your arrays are numpy arrays):

```
idx = (s1 > 0) & (s1 > s2)
s3[idx] = s1[idx]

idy = (s1 > 0) & (s1 <= s2)
s3[idy] = s2[idy]

idz = (s1 < 0)
s3[idz] = 0
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np
s1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,-1])
s2 = np.array([2,1,3,4,-2])

# initialize s3
s3 = np.ones(len(s1))

# do some numpy indexing magic 
idx = (s1 > 0) & (s1 > s2)
s3[idx] = s1[idx]

idy = (s1 > 0) & (s1 <= s2)
s3[idy] = s2[idy]

idz = (s1 < 0)
s3[idz] = 0

print s3
# [ 2.  2.  3.  4.  0.]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in enumerate(s1):
    c1 = int(s1[i] < 0)
    c2 = int(s1[i]>s2[i])

    s3[i] =  c1*0 + int(not c1)*( s1[i]*c2 + s2[i]*(not c2) )
```